# Custom Report type with User and Case objects

Tags: reporting

I created a custom report type with User as primary object and Case(Case Owner) as secondary object. I am trying to build a report which gives Cases Count by Agent. Counts has to be the users(from two profiles)and a Queue. But the report is displaying only cases created by Users but not cases assigned to queue. Please let me know the report type i created is correct or not. I could able to query accurate results through soql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard 'Cases' type report could give you the case owner - whether user or queue.

***Update*** 
Based on your comment, I'd recommend to create a Custom formula field on `Case` where you could determine your category based on your custom `Department` picklist field value on `User`, or by `Queue` name.
When you use User as a Master object for custom report type, it automatically filtering out `Case` records owned by queue as it a [cross-object field](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/cross-object-owner-fields-a-powerful-new-formula-option.html) but you want to use only one.

Comment: I have added User object as we have added custom field - Department which is is a picklist to group users with different profiles under one department(Eg. Sales Support Agent and Sales Support Manager belongs to same department.). That is the reason why I have created custom report type. But with Case( owner), i am not able to get user and queue.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, instead of adding the case owner as a secondary object just have the case object alone and add the lookup fields to the record to the page layout. This will allow you to create a case report and include additional fields related to the owner.
[image: Add related fields]